# Downgrading .deb package, can't find the version I need

Tags: apt, package-management

I need to downgrade `qbittorrent-nox` from `3.3.13` to `3.3.11`, but I can't find the older version with `apt`.

Output of `apt list -a qbittorrent-nox`:

```
Listing... Done
qbittorrent-nox/now 3.3.13-0ppa1~xenial amd64 [installed,local]
qbittorrent-nox/xenial 3.3.1-1 amd64
```

Seems like the only older version I can get is `3.3.1-1`.

Output of `apt-cache policy qbittorrent-nox`:

```
qbittorrent-nox:
  Installed: 3.3.13-0ppa1~xenial
  Candidate: 3.3.13-0ppa1~xenial
  Version table:
 *** 3.3.13-0ppa1~xenial 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.3.1-1 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

Can't find an older `.deb` in `/var/cache/apt/archives` either.

The package is from [their PPA](https://launchpad.net/~qbittorrent-team/+archive/ubuntu/qbittorrent-stable?field.series_filter=xenial), but I'm not sure if they keep older releases around. I could always compile from source, but the bug I have is fixed but not yet released, but will be in the coming days so I'd like to stick with the package manager, and temporarily `apt-mark hold qbittorrent-nox` when it is at version `3.3.11`, until the patch is released in `3.3.14`.

Comment: The package is available in the official repositories, but it's version 3.3.7 - I suspect that your version comes from the qbittorrent-team stable repositories.  Can you check this with `apt-cache policy qbittorrent-nox`?

Comment: Hey Charles, thank you for reaching out. I've added the output of `apt-cache policy qbittorrent-nox` to the post. Does the ppa from the qbittorrent-team keep older releases around perhaps?

Comment: Thanks - I'm not sure where you downloaded 3.3.13 from (I'm a beginner myself), but it looks like the version at [https://launchpad.net/~qbittorrent-team/+archive/ubuntu/qbittorrent-stable](https://launchpad.net/~qbittorrent-team/+archive/ubuntu/qbittorrent-stable), downloaded rather than installed via ppa

Comment: Indeed it does. I don't recall adding their PPA repo manually, but it looks like I did. Browsing that link you provided doesn't seem to show any older releases. Any clues where I might find an older release?

Comment: Not from me, I'm sorry to say.  My only suggestion (a poor one) would be to remove 3.3.13 and install 3.3.1 from the repositories, but I suspect that's older than you want to use.

Comment: Ah, bummer! Well thank you for pointing me in the right direction at least!

Comment: You were on the right track with Launchpad. LP does indeed keep archive versions of old builds. See https://launchpad.net/~qbittorrent-team/+archive/ubuntu/qbittorrent-stable/+builds?build_state=built

Comment: @user535733  That's really interesting!  I had gotten to that page, but not scrolled past the build logs, and thus did not see the older deb files.  I will have to try to remember that for future reference...